# nodejs, redis, npm and docker-compose setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like install nodejs, npm, redis and memcached with docker and docker-compose.
But i did not install only redis (by [document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-1-setup)).

I did next: 
1 install docker, docker-compose
2 create  folder: ~/app 
3 in catalog was create Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, app.py,requirements.txt

**requirements.txt:**

`redis`

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
count = redis.incr('hits')
return 'Hello World! I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM redis:3.2-stable
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "app.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

run compose  `docker-compose up -d` and have error

> Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket -
>   is it running? If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL
>   with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

What is problem? How setup at least one redis ?

**P.S.** If you know how install with docker-compose nodejs npm and memcached
I will be grateful

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @Confidence Ubuntu 14, core -  lts

Answer (score 0):

Mybe it not good solution, but don't found another. I found on [github](https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/tree/master/05-nginx-express-redis-nodemon) ready-made solution.

1. Install docker and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/) (docs.docker.com/compose/install/)
2. Create folder (my project in /var/www/example.com)
3. Run docker-compose build.
4. Run docker-compose up

Answer (score 0):

How about add `sudo` before your command?